# Killing query created by another application

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, kill

I have a Java application where I want to be able to kill queries made to several databases. I know how to get the queries in the information_schema.processlist, but the problem is I don't know how to kill those queries. Usually I would do it using KILL command, but I cant use it in java application (or at least I havent figured out how to do it).

I've been reading about the Statement.cancel but the problem is that the queries are created by another application. I've understood that you have to have Statement variable in the class where you want to cancel it.

if I can use Statement for this purpose, can someone please help me to understand how. I'm using MySQL database. I dont want to set timeout, because I want to be able to kill any query I want to.

These are some examples how I've tried to kill the process:

```
public synchronized void killProcesses(Set<Long> ids) {
    for (long id : ids) {
        String killCommand="Select 'KILL ' from processlist where id=:id";

        Query query= queryManager.createQuery(killCommand);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        query.getResultList();
    }
}

public synchronized void killProcesses(Set<Long> ids) {
    for (long id : ids) {
        String killCommand="KILL " + id;

        Query query= queryManager.createQuery(killCommand);
        query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem/error message with your second attempt? I think you should try [`Statement.executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) instead of trying to `getResultList()`.

Comment: @HannoBinder The exception I get is:Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [KILL QUERY71427]. 
[0, 15] The query does not start with a valid identifier, has to be either SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE FROM.

Comment: Use `Statement.execute()` to execute arbitrary SQL. As the exception says, the method you are using only supports select, update or delete

Comment: I tried `query.executeUpdate()` but got pretty much the same exception. The problem with Statement is that I use entityManager, so I just can't crete Statement, but I think I'll try to unwrap the connection and create Statement with it.

Comment: I tried to unwrap the connection and create and execute the statement but I'm getting nullpointer. It appears that `queryManager.unwrap(Connection.class)` returns null. I first thought it's because I always close the connection after transaction but I removed that from my persistence.xml and it still doesnt work. I'm using Eclipselink.

Comment: Forgot to use `queryManager.getTransaction().begin();` first. Now it's working. Thank you for your help @HannoBinder and @Romski !

Comment: You could also use the EM to [create a native query](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29); might work without any unwrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HannoBinder solved the problem, the final solution is:

```
private String killQuery(long id) {
    String killCommand="KILL " + id;
    queryManager.getTransaction().begin();
    Query query=queryManager.createNativeQuery(killCommand);
    query.executeUpdate();
    queryManager.getTransaction().commit();
    return "OK";
}
```

And one that worked too, but isnt that simple:

```
public synchronized void killProcesses(Set<Long> ids) {
    for (long id : ids) {
        String killCommand="KILL QUERY " + id;
        queryManager.getTransaction().begin();
        Connection conn=queryManager.unwrap(Connection.class);
        try {
            Statement statement= conn.createStatement();
            statement.execute(killCommand);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
                queryManager.getTransaction().commit();
                conn.close();   
        }

    }
}
```